# How to debug stopped `ProcessPoolExecutor`?

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I have a system that read and parse data with `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, but few times a week it got stuck. I've used rpyc to debug it and saw the `_queue_management_thread` (deamon thread) is stopped. I can't see any exception thrown in the system, and I wonder how to proceed

Comment: Can you please provide some code snippets of the ProcessPoolExecutor block and Process worker method?

Comment: I don't use it in a `with` block, I have an executor object and I run `executor.submit` to my function (many times (few times a second) for long period (days))